# concept for check and out-of-bounds

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying to define a `C++20 concept` that enforces the implementors to check for an out of bounds.

```
template <size_t Num>
concept IsInBounds = requires (const size_t idx) {
    requires idx >= Num;
};
```

So, for a method that I have in a custom container that returns a non-const reference to an element inside it, I want to check with the concept if the index required is out-of-bounds.

```
auto mut_ref_at(const size_t idx) const -> T(&) requires IsInBounds<N>
{
    return (T&) array[idx];
}
```

That's obviously doesn't works:

```
error: substitution into constraint expression resulted in a non-constant expression
    requires idx >= Num;

function parameter 'idx' with unknown value cannot be used in a constant expression
    requires idx >= Num;
```

So, if I understand something about concepts, the concept is understanding that the `requires (const size_t idx)` clause, where I have a parameter idx, is substituting the parameter `idx` of my method?

And, exists some way with the concept of constraint the value `idx` of the `mut_ref_at` method to the size of the `T array[N]` member?

Full class declaration:

```
template <typename T, zero::size_t N>
    class StackArray{
        private:
            T array[N];
        public:
            template <typename... InitValues>
            StackArray(InitValues... init_values) 
                : array{ init_values... } {}

            /**
             * @brief delete the `new` operator, since the intended usage of
             * the type is to be a wrapper over a C-style array.
             * 
             * @return void* 
             */
            void* operator new(std::size_t) = delete;

            /**
             * @brief Returns a mut reference to the element at specified location `idx`,
             * with bounds checking.
             * 
             * @param idx a `size_t` value for specifiying the position of 
             * the element to retrieve.
             * @return T& to the element at idx position
             */
            constexpr auto mut_ref_at(const size_t idx) const -> T(&) requires IsInBounds<N>
            {
                return (T&) array[idx];
            }
```

Edit: changed concept declaration

Comment: what is `type` ? Also unclear what you expect from `sizeof(type) / sizeof(type)`. Its always 1.

Comment: `template <std::size_t I> requires (I < N) auto at() /*..*/`?

Comment: Function parameters are never constexpr (template parameters are).

Comment: The requires expression does not evaluate an expression, it merely specifies whether the expression is supported by the types.  Sandor Dargo wrote a nice introduction to Concepts, for further details check out the C++20 books from Rainer Grimm and Nico Josuttis.  Also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weJD_ZCr6S8

Comment: Was this meant to be `sizeof(T) / sizeof(T[0])` ?

Comment: Sorry about the wrong concept declaration. Was one of the multiple infernal non-sense tries.

Comment: @Jarod, that's makes sense. So, for get the value determined at compile time, I must mimic the `std::get<...>` implementation but for my member method? So, client code must provide the index through template param right?

Comment: What's up with the `(T&)` cast in `return`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is the unique way that I know to return a ref to an array element from a function in C++. Also, I guess that I can use `decltype(auto)` and avoid return trailing type

Comment: @HolyBlackCat how should I write the return to return a reference?

Comment: Just remove the cast. Also note that `-> T(&)` is the same thing as `-> T &`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat for that to work, I must remove also the const qualifier over the method. Is that fine? ```auto mut_ref_at() -> T& {return array[idx];}```

Comment: I didn't notice it. Why do you have a const method return a non-const reference? Yes, you should either remove the const or return a const reference (normally you have two methods for the two cases). The cast is unnecessary in both cases.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh, thanks, You're completly right. Also, I want to have the overload for the const ref (or better, a `const_ref_at()`), not `mut_ref_at()` method, but I am struggling on how I must write the code to return a const ref.

Comment: You don't need to do anything, set the return type to `const T &` and return `array[idx]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat perfect! Was thinking that I must provide some specific cast-conversion-something that qualifies my return value as const, but they are provided as const thanks to the method signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to provide the `out-of-bounds` checking at compile time, you must provide the index via template parameter. You should rely on a `std::size_t` value to provide the index that the client code wants to retrieve, and, with the concept, index will be determined when the template is instanciated. This will lead the compiler to refuse to compile if the index is `out-of-bounds`.

Your code will looks like:

```
template <size_t I, size_t N>
concept IsInBounds = requires () {
    requires I <= N;
};
```

You use your class template parameter `N` to determine the array capacity. So, you can check I against N. If I is greater than N, concept will fail, and code will not compile.

And your method will looks like:

```
template <size_t I>
constexpr T& mut_ref_at() requires IsInBounds<I, N>
{
    return arr[I];
}
```

Note that, as others pointed out, cast to `(T&)` it's ugly and unnecessary. Trailing return is also verbose, the return type it's clearly always `T&`.

Comment: Just checked it out and works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Valid indexes are `I < N` though ;-)

Comment: Concept seems superfluous, `/*..*/ mut_ref_at() requires(I < N)` would be enough.

Comment: @Jarod42 seems like the OP is trying to make an API/library, so I assumed that will be a lot of places using `requires(I < N)`. But nice point